# Adding slashes to the end of directories + more (htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is beyond my level and I need some help.

In the htaccess make redirect rules for the following...

1. if `example.com/1stleveldirectory` doesn't end in a slash add one.
2. if `example.com/1stleveldirectory/` ends in a slash don't add anything.
3. if `example.com/1stleveldirectory/file` is like this add .html.
4. if `example.com/1stleveldirectory/file.html` is like this don't add anything.

There are no publicly accessible directories past the first level

Thanks!

EDIT: I should have said I already have this code at the top of the file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.([^.]+.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?cat=$1&name=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond $0 !.+\.html$
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for you response but It didn't work properly. I added some more information to the question.